# Using tether with webpack (Angular CLI)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, tether

I'm developing a project using Angular CLI.
So I installed tether using `npm install tether --save`, and imported the depedency in app.component.ts
using `import * as Tether from 'tether'`.

When I try to initialize Tether with `new Tether({ ... })` it prints the following error in the console:

> EXCEPTION: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_tether is not a constructor

If I print the Tether variable using `console.log(Tether)` it gives me what is seems an empty object.

Could you guys help me? I've never used neither typescript nor webpack before, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using  bootstrap4 then tether.js is already a dependency.
This might work

**Using Angular-cli**

First, install Bootstrap from npm:

**npm install bootstrap@next**

```
Then add the needed script files to angular-cli.json --> scripts:



 "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
           ],

Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the angular-cli.json --> styles array:

    "styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"`enter code here`
],

Restart ng serve if you're running it, and Bootstrap 4 should be working on your app.
```

**For Webpack**

If you are using webpack:

Set up bootstrap-loader as described in docs;

Install tether.js via npm;

Add tether.js to the webpack ProvidePlugin plugin:

```
 plugins: [
        <... your plugins here>,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.Tether": 'tether'
        })
    ]
```

**Bootstrap 4 is no longer using tag window.tether**

```
Note that using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6,
```

Bootstrap is no longer checking for "window.Tether" 
but the global variable "Tether", 
so the webpack configuration becomes

```
plugins: [
    <... your plugins here>,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "Tether": 'tether'
    })
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Angular-cli, you'll have to add that to your angular-cli.json

In your file(angular-cli.json) include it under the scripts array:

```
 "scripts": [
            "other/scripts/you've used"
            "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
            "../node_modules/tether-shepherd/dist/js/shepherd.min.js"
        ],
```

Include the css in styles.

Hope this works out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `import Tether from 'tether';` This imports the default export of tether which happens to be the [`TetherClass`](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether/blob/4de1f5c/src/js/tether.js#L178) you're trying in instantiate.

The code `import * as Tether` imports all (default and named) exports of the library, and you'd need to `new Tether.TetherClass()`.

Check out the great [**Exploring ES6** book on modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) for details.

Comment: If I try `import Tether from 'tether'` or `import * as Tether` using `new Tether.TetherClass()` the same error occurs: it tells me that this object is not a constructor. And if I console.log TetherClass I get null :(

Comment: The way I was trying to convey is `import Tether from 'tether'; new Tether();`. If this does not work: which version of Tether are you using?

Comment: tether version 1.4.0

Comment: Here's a working Gist: https://gist.github.com/simon04/121f210379a0bff9669b34ad26196fcc

Comment: I installed another package called physicsjs and it worked fine. I'm going to create a new project and add tether again to see if it's some incompatibility with my current project. I'm using bootstrap 4, which happens to have tether as a dependency. Does that affect in any way?

Comment: Ok, It seems it was some problem with my project. I created a new one using `ng new project-name`, installed both tether and @types/tether and it works. Thanks for your help anyway!